# Placing three figures side by side, each with its own caption

Tags: captions, positioning, minipage

I'm trying to place three images side by side each with its own caption. The code written below works great with the placement of the images, but the captions don't. When compiling it only shows the last caption placed under the first image, and no captions on the other two images. How can i fix this?

The code i've written is this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
\caption{caption1}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2}
\caption{caption2}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image3}
\caption{caption3}
\label{fig:figure3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `subfigure` environment and `subcaption` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just replace the two `\hspace{0.5cm}` directives with `\hfill` and you'll be all set.

Comment: @Mico - I just tried it, and it still only gives me the one caption on the wrong image.

Comment: @AndersThonSletsjøe - Did you replace *both* instances of `\hspace{0.5cm}` with `\hfill`?

Comment: Yes, @Mico . And I also may have been unclear. I want the images to have its own number. Not like: Figure 1.3 (a) (b) (c)

Comment: @AndersThonSletsjøe - Please see the answer I just posted. If this answer isn't working for you, it may be because you're using an unusual document class. Please do reveal with document class you employ.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using the package subfig:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
 \centering
 \captionabove{Images}%
 \label{fig:images}
 \subfloat[left]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
      \label{fig:image-a}
 \qquad
 \subfloat[mid]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
      \label{fig:image-b}
 \qquad
 \subfloat[right]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
      \label{fig:image-c}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this solution with `floatrow` will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering %
\floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad}
\begin{floatrow}[3]%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{caption1}\label{fig:figure1}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{image1}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{caption2}\label{fig:figure2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{image2}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{caption3}\label{fig:figure3}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{image3}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there: Just replace both instances of `\hspace{0.5cm}` with `\hspace{\fill}` or, more succinctly, `\hfill`.

While you're at it, you should also delete the three redundant `\centering` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
%\centering  % redundant
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
\caption{caption1}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill% not: "\hspace{0.5cm}"
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
%\centering  % redundant
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2}
\caption{caption2}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill% not: "\hspace{0.5cm}"
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
%\centering  % redundant
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image3}
\caption{caption3}
\label{fig:figure3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. Im using \documentclass{report}

Comment: @AndersThonSletsjøe - First off, if one replaces `article` with `report` in the code above, all three captions continue to show up as they should. Second, if the solution isn't not working for you, it *must* be the case that there's something else going on in your document which you haven't revealed so far. Sadly, my psychic skills are absolutely worthless; the chances of me guessing (correctly) what's going on in your document are nil. Please go back to your original posting and edit it in such a way that it (a) becomes compilable and (b) reproduces the problem behavior you wish to solve.

Comment: Tried changing to article document class, still no luck. Everything else works totally fine. The document compiles with no errors. The problem I have is described in my original post.

Comment: @AndersThonSletsjøe - A comment such as "still no luck" is not helpful. The code I posted in answer above generates the screenshot shown above. If you are *not* getting this result when using the `article` (or `report`) document class, the only possible reason is that there's some code in your document that's interfering. But as long as you don't provide information sufficient to replicate the problem you say you're getting, chances of anyone guessing correctly what may be going on are decidedly slim.

Comment: Well then I dont know what to do. There are no other problems what so ever with the document. No error messages. I dont know what to tell you. I appreciate you helping tho!

Comment: @AndersThonSletsjøe - You wrote, "Well then I dont know what to do." I've already given you a specific suggestion: Go back to your query and edit the code so that it actually generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. That'll provide the information that's needed to come up with (a) a full diagnosis and (b) a cure (hopefully).

Comment: Well when i type in the code i wrote in the original post, it creates the problem i descibed.

Comment: @AndersThonSletsjøe - The code in your posting is a code snippet, i.e., it is *not compilable* as stated. For instance, it is missing a `\documentclass` statement, it doesn't load the `graphicx` package, and it's lacking `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` statements. And because your code is not compilable, it can *by definition* not generate the problem behavior you wish to fix. In my answer, I made your code snippet compilable by furnishing sensible-looking additions; so far, your attempt at a rejoinder is of the unhelpful "still no luck" variety. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Ah ok, now i understand. I tried opening a new document and using the code you wrote. Worked perfectly! That means that there is something wrong in my preamble file. Do you know if any packages interferes with the \graphicx package?

Comment: @AndersThonSletsjøe - Suggestion: Edit your query and post the contents of the preamble.