# How to line up two images with different titles side by side in Elsevier cas-dc class?

Tags: floats, double-sided, els-cas

I am using elsevier's template - `cas-dc`, and I would like to have two images with different titles side by side **in a double-column**.
But the captions don't appear directly below the image, one of the captions is in the middle of the whole article.

And there is an overfull error reported.

ps: I referred to answers with similar questions and did not get a solution.
[Placing three figures side by side, each with its own caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484688/257407)

```
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Fig1.pdf}
        \caption{Problems due to rivet aging}
        \label{fig-problemofrivet}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Fig1.pdf}
        \caption{Example of rivet replacement by the bolt}
        \label{fig-rivetrepla}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Comment: That class seems pretty broken, imho. The captions always use the `\linewidth` which was correct somewhere in the preamble...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class has some hard design flaws (contained in `cas-common.sty`). I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to mess with the code of it, but the following patch should do:

**EDIT:** since there might be problems with unconditionally defining `\bibsep` I've changed it to do that only if it isn't yet defined, and do that pretty late.

```
\documentclass[]{cas-dc}

\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{\ifdefined\bibsep\else\newlength\bibsep\fi} % class is broken...

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:NNno \exp_args:Nno \use:n { \cs_gset:Npn \__make_fig_caption:nn #1#2 }
  {
    \exp_after:wN \use_ii_i:nn \exp_after:wN
      { \__make_fig_caption:nn {#1} {#2} }
      { \dim_set:Nn \l_fig_width_dim \linewidth }
  }
\exp_args:NNno \exp_args:Nno \use:n { \cs_gset:Npn \__make_tbl_caption:nn #1#2 }
  {
    \exp_after:wN \use_ii_i:nn \exp_after:wN
      { \__make_tbl_caption:nn {#1} {#2} }
      { \dim_set:Nn \l_tbl_width_dim \linewidth }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\blindduck[all]
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Problems due to rivet aging\label{fig-problemofrivet}}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Example of rivet replacement by the bolt\label{fig-rivetrepla}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\blindduck[all]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!   I tried adding this patch, and now the side-by-side figure can work correctly.

Comment: @YuChen there is more than that wrong with the internals of the class and package (some things seem to be half added but then abandoned, etc., for instance the `figure` environment accepts an optional key=value list with a key `cols`, but that key effectively does nothing!), if you find a maintainer for this class you should send them a bug report, imho.

Comment: I'll try to give them feedback on such errors. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had the same problem and now the code works correctly. However, this leads to a new error: "LaTeX Error: Command \bibsep already defined" ... How can I fix this?

Comment: @Elisa - Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated? The reason I ask is that I am unable to replicate the issue you say you're encountering on my system (MacTeX2022 w/ all updates applied) and `cas-dc` version `2021/05/11, 2.3`.

Comment: @Elisa I'm sorry to hear you got issues, unfortunately with such a short description in the comment there is nothing much I can do. You could try the following instead of the `\newlength\bibsep`-line: `\ifdefined\bibsep\else\newlength\bibsep\fi`, if that doesn't work try `\AtBeginDocument{\ifdefined\bibsep\else\newlength\bibsep\fi`, if that doesn't work, please create a new question with a minimal example (linking to this answer inside that question might be a good idea then).

Comment: (forget about the new question part, just saw you already did that... :))